# 3 questions about generators and iterators in Python

Tags: python, generator

Everyone says you lose the benefit of generators if you put the result into a list.

1. But you need a list, or a sequence, to even have a generator to begin with, right? So, for example, if I need to go through the files in a directory, don't I have to make them into a list first, like with os.listdir()? If so, then how is that more efficient? (I am always working with strings and files, so I really hate that all the examples use range and integers, but I digress)
2. Taking it a step further, the mere presence of the yield keyword is supposed to make a generator. So if I do:

   ```
   for x in os.listdir():
       yield x
   ```

Is a list still being created? Or is os.listdir() itself now also magically a generator? Is it possible that, os.listdir() not having been called yet, that there really *isn't* a list here yet?

3. Finally, we are told that iterators need **iter**() and **next**() methods. But doesn’t that also mean they need an index? If not, what is next() operating on? How does it know what is next without an index? Before 3.6, dict keys had no order, so how did that iteration work?

Comment: `itertools.count()` iterates over integers indefinitely, so it better not pre-allocate a `list`.

Comment: if `os.listdir():` creates a list - there will be one. you are just yielding the lements of it - let me check it for you:  [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) : `Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path.` - so: yep, there will be a list

Answer (score 1):

1. No.

See, there's no list here:

```
def one():
    while True:
        yield 1
```

3. Index and `next()` are two independent tools to perform an iteration. Again, if you have an object such that its iterator's `next()` always returns 1, you don't need any indices.

In deeper detail...

See, technically, you can always associate a list and an index with any generator or iterator: simply write down all its returned values — you'll get at most countable set of values a₀, a₁, ... But those are merely a mathematical formalism quite unnecessarily having anything in common with how a real generator works. For instance, you have a generator that always yields one. You can count how many ones have you got from it so far, and call that an index. You can write down all that ones, comma-separated, and call that a list. Do those two objects correctly describe your elapsed generator's output? Apparently so. Are they in a least bit important for the generator itself? Not really.

Of course, a real generator will probably have a state (you can call it an index—provided you don't necessarily call something an index if it is only a non-negative integral scalar; you can write down all its states, provided it works deterministically, number them and call current state's number index—yes, approximately that). They will always have a source of their states and returned values. So, indices and lists can be regarded as *abstractions* that describe object's behaviour. But quite unnecessary they are concrete implementation details that are really used.

Consider unbuffered file reader. It retrieves a single byte from the disk and immediately yields it. There's no a real list in memory, only the file contents on the disk (there may even be no, if our file reader is connected to a net socket instead of a real disk drive, and the Oracle of Delphi is at connection's other end). You can call file position index—until you read the stdin, which is only forward-traversable and thus indexing it makes no real physical sense—same goes for network connections via unreliable protocol, BTW.

Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

1) This is wrong; it is just the easiest example to explain a generator from a list. If you think of the 8 queens-problem and you return each position as soon as the program finds it, I can't recognize a result list anywhere. Note, that often iterators are alternately offered even by python standard library (`islice()` vs. `slice()`, and an easy example not representable by a list is `itertools.cycle()`.

In consequence 2 and 3 are also wrong.